# Returning numbers from d3.random

Tags: javascript, d3.js, higher-order-functions

I want to ask about the return type of variables/functions. I have some sample code like this:

```
var randomX = d3.randomNormal(mean, 80),      
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(mean, 80),     
    points = d3.range(1000).map(function() {return [randomX(), randomY()]; });
```

`randomX` and `randomY` were declared as variables, why in the `return` line they were `randomX()` and `randomY()` with the parentheses?

I'm new to Javascript, please help me out here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That means they are of `function` type

Comment: `randomNormal` must return functions, not numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Is it right that the actual random numbers appear when we call that function again? (I mean, does randomX() return a random number?)

Comment: @iomagenta We can't know for sure. What is `d3`? It would appear as though that's the case.

Comment: Okay I got it. D3 is a JS library for manipulating documents based on data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but take a look at this example:

```
function fn1(inputNumber) {
    return function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * inputNumber)
    }
}

var bigRand = fn1(10000);
console.log(bigRand());
console.log(bigRand());
```

This is sorta like what the d3.randomNormal is doing. You're creating a new function via closure, mostly in this case so you don't have to repeat the same input over and over. This is effectively the same as doing the following:

```
function fn2(inputNumber) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * inputNumber)
}

console.log(fn2(10000));
console.log(fn2(10000));
```

See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add the specific D3 information to the comments and to the accepted answer (which covers the question very well): `d3.randomNormal()` returns a **function**.

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-random) is clear:

> Returns a **function** for generating random numbers with a normal (Gaussian) distribution. (emphasis mine)

You can also see this if you inspect the source code:

```
export default (function sourceRandomNormal(source) {
  function randomNormal(mu, sigma) {
      //bunch of code here...
  };
  return randomNormal;//returns the function here!
});
```

So, if you want to get the actual numbers, you have to call it (with parentheses):

```
d3.randomNormal([mu][, sigma])()
//parentheses here------------^
```

Let's prove it.

First, without parentheses:

```js
var random = d3.randomNormal(10, 1);
console.log(random);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Now with the parentheses:

```js
var random = d3.randomNormal(10, 1)();
console.log(random);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```